# Formik handleSubmit does nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have two components that both contain a form and I am implementing Formik in each component in exactly the same way, yet in one component `handleSubmit` is working and in the other component it is not.

The component code can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/chris-haupt/c6c0e22851b03a74e504a5ee94a774bd

I am simply trying to run *any* code in the callback that is being passed to the `onSubmit` prop. Previously I was able to do this without a problem by passing `handleSubmit` to the form element.

When I click the submit button, or press enter, nothing happens. Nothing at all. If I pass a `console.log` to `onSubmit` on the form element then the log fires just fine. So for some reason there is a disconnect where `handleSubmit` is not being passed correctly.

The final bit of evidence I have is a `console.log` of `onSubmit.toString()`:

```js
function () {
    for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
      args[_key] = arguments[_key];
    }

    return ref.current.apply(void 0, args);
  }
```

But this code means very little to me :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `handleSubmit` function doesn't fire if there are any errors in the `errors` object. In this case I was passing `formikValidation` to the `validate` prop and this was checking for fields that don't exist on this component so it would always return an error stating that the field was empty.